# Setting media query for large sizes

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to understand media queries and I want to set a css value for screens larger then 13 inches

Is this the correct syntax?

```
@media all and (min-width : 992px) {
    .myElement{
        width: 100px;
    }
```

or

```
@media all and (@screen-md-min) {
    .myElement{
        width: 200px;
    }
```

what's the difference here?

Comment: There is no difference. Although Bootstrap has this in example - `/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }`. Without the `all and`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the resolution and quality. For a 72 PPI (pixels per inch) screen (average resolution), 13 inches are equal to 72 x 13 = 936 pixels. Therefore, the syntax you will use is:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 936px) {
  .myElement {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

Edit: Increase the `min-width` a little to apply the style only for screens wider than 13". But again, this depends on the resolution and quality of the screen.

Comment: The problem I have is that when I move my window from my 13 inch laptop to my 22 inch monitor and resize to full screen, shouldn't I see the effects change? I don't and when I look in the debugger the media query value has a line slashed through it!

Comment: Do you need this style for screens **wider than 13"** or for screens **13" or wider** ?

Comment: I guess wider then 13''